Meaning of 這個故事敘述一個自絕於人群之外的孤獨男人。
這個故事敘述一個自絕於人群之外的孤獨男人。
自絕 = 自行斷絕 = Voluntarily cutting off all contact
於人群 = With crowds/other people
之外 = beyond?
So it means a lonely man cutting off all contact with others, but what does 之外 mean here? I don't really understand it and it seems superfluous to have it here because the sentence works perfectly fine without it.
Thanks for the help.

He is in the state of 自绝 (having voluntarily put himself) outside the 人群?

"...自絕於人群之外...." -- "Far from the Madding Crowd"  :)

I think his question is: why is the word 之外 used in this passage?

@James  I thought you described yourself in your Profile as "I am a newbie just arrived on earth. I know nothing about everything"  :)

自絕 - alienate oneself
於 - from
之外 - outside, beyond
I think the author meant to say "he is a lonely person who alienated himself from the crowd - 自絕於人群的孤獨男人, Here, "之外" does not make good sense. it makes sense only if the sentence is changed to - "一個自絕於人群. 活在人群之外, 的孤獨男人. - "a lonely person who alienated himself from the crowd and lived/stayed outside of the crowd"

敘述: narrate, tell, recount
自絕: 与……断绝联系：指刻意避免与某人或某事物有任何关系
自绝：with …… sever relations: refers to deliberately avoiding any kind of relations with someone or something
於（于）…之外: in … outside (Chinese likes to encapsulate phrases this way. 从海上涌来， 从椅子上，于书本上， 于减少世界上的)
這個故事敘述一個自絕於人群之外的孤獨男人。
这个故事叙述一个自绝于人群之外孤独的男人。
This story tells of a lonely man who cuts himself off from the crowd.
Provenance:

Hardy, who lifted it from "Far from the madding crowd's ignoble
strife," a line of Gray's "Elegy" (1749), which seems to echo and
smooth a line from Drummond of Hawthornden from 1614 ("Farre from the
madding Worldling's hoarse discords").

